# Switch an image according to the H2 text in Jquery

Tags: jquery, kentico

I'm new to the whole jQuery thing. 
I'm trying to create a website in kentico CMS, what I want is to change the header image according to the `h2` header content. So each different page gets an different image.

I've tried with `.addClass`, `.css` and `.attr` but nothing seems to work. The jQuery I have tried is the following:

```
$(document).ready (function() {
{

var title = $('h2').text(); 

switch(title)
{
    case 'About us':
        $('.contentHeader').addClass('contentAbout')
        break;
    case 'Education':
        $('.contentHeader').css('background-image','url(/edu.png)')
        break;
    case 'Projects':
        $('.contentHeader').attr('src','/projects.png')
        break;
    case 'Benefits':
        $('.contentHeader').attr('src','/benefits.png')
        break;
    default:

}



)};
```

So basically I want to change the header to `edu.png` if the `h2`'s text = Education.

Comment: Did you try to debug it? Try putting alert to see what value is coming in title variable ?

Comment: Please add your html aswell. That will help us find the error.

Comment: All your approaches look valid and correct, depending on the HTML and CSS to which you're applying this solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to change `)};` to `});` last line, and if you don't need `default:` , don't use it.

Also remove `{` from line 2 (thanks Peter)

```
$(function() { // DOM ready (shorthand)

    var title = $('h2').text(); 

    switch(title){
        case 'About us':
            $('.contentHeader').addClass('contentAbout');
            break;
        case 'Education':
            $('.contentHeader').css('background-image','url(/edu.png)');
            break;
        case 'Projects':
            $('.contentHeader').attr('src','/projects.png');
            break;
        case 'Benefits':
            $('.contentHeader').attr('src','/benefits.png');
            break;
    }

});
```

You can also do it this way:

```
$(function(){ 

  var title = $('h2').text(); 

  var changes = {
    'About us'  : ['addClass', 'contentAbout'],
    'Education' : ['css',      {backgroundImage: "url(/edu.png)"}],
    'Projects'  : ['attr',     {src: "/projects.png"}],
    'Benefits'  : ['attr',     {src: "/benefits.png"}]
  };

  var method = changes[title][0];
  var valu   = changes[title][1];

  $('.contentHeader')[method](valu);

});
```

Comment: Also remove the extra { on line 2

Comment: I changed the )}; to }); and removed the { from line 2, nothing seems to happen. My html is
 <div class="contentHeader"></div>
<div class="h2back"><h2><%# Eval("ContentTitle") %></h2></div>
<div class="contenttxt"><%# Eval("ContentText") %></div>

My Css is:
.contentHeader
{
  
    width: 837px;
    margin-left: -20px;
   height: 140px;
   border: none;
}

.contentAbout
{
   background-image: url('aboutusbanner.png');
    width: 837px;
    margin-left: -20px;
   height: 140px;
   border: none;
}